# Linking galvanic cell and power supply for electrolysis of water

Tags: electrochemistry

[image]

- P- Power supply
- Circle - Water electrolyzer
- - and + are the terminals
- The salt bridge is soaked in potassium nitrate
- Electrolytes - magnesium nitrate and zinc nitrate

The water electrolyzer is made of distilled water and sodium bicarbonate ($\pu{1.5 L}$ of distilled water and $\pu{60 g}$ of sodium bicarbonate)

They are connected in series. The power supply and the galvanic cell should add, but it is not working out.

Is the problem the galvanic cell?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean like so it is not possible to have 2 electrolytic cells? (I am new to this topic sorry)

Comment: This is like a project of mine and I wanted to understand why isn't it possible could you explain to me?

Comment: Well like I tried to use the (Galvanic cell and power supply) to electrolyze water. I did this becuase my galvanic cell didn't provide enough to electroylze water, so I needed a power supply. When I performed it with the powers supply alone it worked, but not with galvnic cell.

Comment: I tried to also do that and it made no difference I had some help of like some teachers also and they couldn't also make it work

Comment: Yeah the current was like very low and it was like 0 amps

Comment: Like when I used the power supplt alone for the electroylysis there was 0 amps but the water was being electroylzed I saw the bubbles forming.

Comment: Comments reformatted and posted as an answer, my comments then deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Why such a strange scenario ? Why would one want to add a galvanic cell to an electrolysis circuit? // Your have polarity of the galvanic cell reversed, having 2 electrolytic cells.

> Sorry what do you mean like so it is not possible to have 2 electrolytic cells? (I am new to this topic sorry). This is like a project of mine and I wanted to understand why isn't it possible could you explain to me?

It is possible to have 2 electrolytic cells, just guessing it is not what you have wanted. From description, it looks you want a galvanic cell and an electrolytic cell.

> Well like I tried to use the (Galvanic cell and power supply) to electrolyze water. I did this becuase my galvanic cell didn't provide enough to electroylze water, so I needed a power supply. When I performed it with the powers supply alone it worked, but not with galvnic cell.

Partly because you have the cell orientation reversed, partly possibly due cell internal resistence, depending on the cell capability.

Key:

- Electrolytic cell mode: + on +, - on -
- Galvanic cell mode: + on -, - on +
- Mg electrode is the - one.
- You have $\ce{Power- -> ^{-}elyt.  cell_1^{+}  -> ^{-}elyt.  cell_1^{+}  -> ^{+}Power}$
- You need $\ce{Power- -> ^{+}galv.  cell_1^{-}  -> ^{-}elyt.  cell_1^{+}  -> ^{+}Power}$

> I tried to also do that and it made no difference I had some help of like some teachers also and they couldn't also make it work –

Then the too high cell resistance comes to the game, not able to pass high enough current. Did you test the cell for current provisioning?

> Yeah the current was like very low and it was like 0 amps.

If you connect 2 water pipes (power and cell) and one is very narrow(cell), it does not matter if the other(power) is very wide.

> Like when I used the power supplt alone for the electroylysis there was 0 amps but the water was being electroylzed I saw the bubbles forming. –

If it was bubbling , the current was > 0.